# C# - How To Validate DateTime ( make "20120713" OR "120713" TO "13.07.2012" )

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, date, formatting

I'm trying to parse a DateTime from EDI-Order ( "20120713" / YYYYMMDD or "120713" / YYMMDD or even other dates WITHOUT dots, so just numbers ) to a valied Date like "DD.MM.YYY" in C#.

I have no idea how many diferent date-formats are in the diferent EDI-Orders, so i'm searching for a solution i can apply to all of them.

thanks everybody.

Comment: I am afraid some assumptions about format will be neccessary, as "120713" could mean 13th of July 2012, 12th of July 2013 and even 7th of December 2013.

Comment: the year is always in the front part, as i've written up there, YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact("20120713", "YYYYMMDD", null);`

Comment: Yes Kuda is right, or you should have some rules how to parse ambignious dte string like he described, but it's better to minimize input format of dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be interested in using this overload of `ParseExact`, you can pass in multiple formats as an array and it will attempt to parse it based on them.(it would be good if you can control the formats and intend on using one for the process)

```
DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact("20120713",
                    new[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyMMdd" },
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact("120713",
                    new[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyMMdd" },
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

For your output you can do `start.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`

Comment: excellent ! :D
but why did u type one for "start" and one for "end" ?
as u try to parse with an array, i can give them both ( 20120713 & 120713 ) for input , can't i ?

Comment: and also the output is DD.MM.YYY HH.MM.

i've just addet .Split(' ')[0] to just get the date.

thank you 4 that ! :D

Comment: Not sure as why you need the `Split` ?

Comment: output from your code is "DD.MM.YYYY HH.MM"
and i just need "DD.MM.YYYY" so i split the output by blank space and just grab the DATE , discarding the TIME ;)

Comment: You have a DateTime instance, you can have `.Date` or you can do a `.ToString(your format)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for multiple formats

```
DateTime Result = new DateTime();
string[] dateFormats = new string[]{ "YYYYMMDD", "YYMMDD", /*other formats you might need*/ };

if (dateFormats.Any(format => DateTime.TryParseExact("yourDate", format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out Result)))
{ /* Result contains the parsed DateTime and you can use it*/ }
else 
{ /* DateTime couldn't be parsed for any format you specified */ }
```