# String conversion to datetime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Is it possible to convert the below date strings to `DateTime` objects?

> ```
> "Friday 31 August 2012";
> "26-Jul-2012"
> "190811"
> ```

I tried in this form:

```
DateTime.TryParse("Friday 31 August 2012"
                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat
                , DateTimeStyles.None
                , out tradeDate);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have to set the culture to en-GB

Comment: `it doesn't work` is a poor description of a problem. Please explain what **is** happening and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 3):

> Is possible to convert this strings in correct datetime? "Friday 31 August 2012"; "26-Jul-2012" "190811"

Yep, as your parsing the dates in specific formats you should use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). `DateTime.TryParse` will internally call [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) which will only attempt to parse the dates using some pre-defined formats. From the docs:

> The DateTime.Parse(String) method tries to convert the string representation of a date and time value to its DateTime equivalent. The string to be parsed can take any of the following forms:
>
> - A string with a date and a time component.
> - A string with a date but no time component.
> - A string with a time but no date component.
> - A string that includes time zone information and conforms to ISO 8601. For example, the first of the following two strings designates the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC); the second designates the time in a time zone seven hours earlier than UTC:
>
>   `2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000Z`
>
>   `2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000-07:00`
> - A string that includes the GMT designator and conforms to the RFC 1123 time format. For example:
>
>   `Sat, 01 Nov 2008 19:35:00 GMT`
> - A string that includes the date and time along with time zone offset information. For example:
>
>   `03/01/2009 05:42:00 -5:00`

It's important to note that when you don't supply these methods any sort of culture information it's taken from the current thread, which if you haven't set explicitly, tends to be that of your machine. So if the dates you are attempting to parse are of that particular culture they will more often than not parse ok e.g. both `"Friday 31 August 2012"`/`"26-Jul-2012"` parse using `TryParse` for me as I my default culture is en-GB, however, `"190811"` fails (I would imagine for all cultures) as it's not a system recognised date format. Hence why `TryParseExact` is more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `ParseExact` format when you know the format of `DateTime`

So to parse "Friday 31 August 2012" use

```
DateTime tradeDate =
DateTime.ParseExact("Friday 31 August 2012", "dddd dd MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The format also has a array overload so you can specify multiple in place of `"dddd dd MMMM yyyy"` for your parsing needs.

[something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686460/570150)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w2sa9yss.aspx) with the proper formats:

```
string[] dateStrings = new[] { "Friday 31 August 2012", "26-Jul-2012", "190811"};
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
string[] formats = new[] { "dddd dd MMMM yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "ddMMyy" };
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = dateStrings
    .Where(ds => DateTime.TryParseExact(ds
        , formats
        , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        , DateTimeStyles.None
        , out date))
    .Select(ds => date);
```

[**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

[**DEMO** with your sample data](http://ideone.com/oDBE7U)

Comment: Nice tim.
The way you have check with Linq with different format.I use to do it in if{} or elseif{} e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParseExact` and supply an array of formatting strings:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("Friday 31 August 2012"
                , new string[] {"dddd dd MMMM yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "ddMMyy"}
                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat
                , DateTimeStyles.None
                , out tradeDate);
```

I suggest reading up on [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.