# Change date format from ddmmyyyy to yyyyddmm

Tags: c#, date

I have a situation where in I might get a date in either of `mmddyyyy` format or `yyyymmdd` format. Now I need to convert any of the received date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.
earlier I was getting date only in the form `yyyymmdd` so I was using

```
Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "yyyy-MM-dd",null)
```

And was getting the required result.

Now I need to put a check on the incoming format of date also.
Is there a simple way of doing that or do I need to put a if else and check everything manually?

Comment: What is the value of `dob` ? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) `The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly`.

Comment: Do you mean the incoming date strings do *not* have separators between the date components, and you do not know which format the incoming date is in?

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686460/570150

Comment: Could you add a date in each format to the question? You say `yyyyMMdd` but seem to parse `yyyy-MM-dd`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try parsing the date with the first format. If parse does is not successful then you parse with the other format:

You should do it this way:

```
//example date
string dateString= "09301986";

//output date
DateTime finalDate;        

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  DateTimeStyles.None, out finalDate))
{
   DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
   DateTimeStyles.None, out finalDate);

}

string finaldate = finalDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I think you mean `MM` (`mm` being minutes) in the format strings, and the order is `MMddyyyy` in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice and helping answer it solved my problem too. 1+

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `TryParseExact` method which allows you to pass a collection of possible formats that you want to support.

```
DateTime dateValue;
var formats = new[] { "MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dob, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
    // do for valid date
}
else
{
    // do for invalid date
}
```

Comment: +1 quite a bit more elegant than my solution, didn't know about the array version :)